# Setting all the values in attribute field to the same value with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

When I use "Update existing fields" in the Field Calculator in QGIS 3.16.0-Hannover, it takes only a second to change all the values in a attribute field to the same value. However when I try to do that with PyQGIS, QGIS crashes.

I have a layer with line geometry with 82800 features inside. I want to change all feature's value inside `"visited"` column to '0'. Here is how I try to do that:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
lines = [feat for feat in layer.getFeatures()]

layer.startEditing()

for line in lines:
    line["visited"] = 0
    layer.updateFeature(line)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Can I do that like I do that with field calculator via using PyQGIS (with expressions or something)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues()` method instead of `layer.updateFeature()`. In this case you don't need to start an edit mode.

```py
import time
    
layer = iface.activeLayer()    
visited_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("visited")
attr_map = {}
new_value = 5

tic = time.perf_counter() ###
for line in layer.getFeatures():
    attr_map[line.id()] = {visited_index: new_value}

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attr_map)
toc = time.perf_counter() ###

print(f"{toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
```

Using dictionary comprehension instead of `for` loop is more convenient to minimize the script.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()    
i = layer.fields().indexFromName("visited") # index of the field

attr_map = {line.id(): {i: 5} for line in layer.getFeatures()} # comprehension    
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attr_map)
```

Comment: It took 3 seconds for 100.000 features in my computer.

Comment: I know some people find comprehensions obtuse, but in this particular case it arguably makes the intent clearer to build `attr_map` using a dict comprehension, e.g.: `attr_map = {feat.id(): {visited_index: 5} for feat in layer.getFeatures()}`.

Comment: @FeRD Yes, thank you. Using comprehension is more convenient.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz does the geometry column have an index so it can be set in a similar way using a dictionary?

Comment: @BERA I don't think there is an index for the geometry in QGIS unlike in ArcGIS. `changeGeometryValues` can be used. Ex: `layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues(geom_attr_map)`