# Add file name as attribute field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a folder with several shapefiles (around 75). I would like to create a new field into each *.shp* file which has to be filename. i.e: 20201003.shp --> 20200103.shp (New field 'Fecha' = 20200103)

I have tried this but nothing is done and no errors neither:

```
import os, datetime


`shapefolder = r'C:\Users\juavafer\Proyectos\Costas_CoastSat\Output\CMillor\Comparacion\matlab\Qgis'
newfieldname = 'test3'

for root, folder, files in os.walk(shapefolder):
    #Find the shapefile
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root,file)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and fullpath.endswith('.shp'):
            print(fullpath)
            #Extract numbers from filename
            datename = ''.join([num for num in file if num.isdigit()])
            #Create a datetime object and convert to string in format 'YYYY-MM-DD', which is what a shapefile wants
            QgsField(name='test3', type=QVariant.String, len=20)
            newdatename = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

        
        print(datename)
        # dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(datename, '%Y%m%d')
        # newdatename = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        print(datename)
        #Add the field https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-adding-and-deleting-vector-layer-fields/
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(fullpath)
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(newfieldname, QVariant.Date)])
        layer.updateFields()
        
        #Update each feature with date https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381174/setting-all-the-values-in-a-attribute-field-to-the-same-value-with-pyqgis)
        attr_map = {}
        field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(newfieldname)
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            attr_map[f.id()] = {field_index: newdatename}
        layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attr_map)`
```

Comment: If you use the attribute table dialog and create a new field using the expression `base_file_name(layer_property(@layer_id,'source'))` you will get that. Not sure how to repeat that over 75 layers though. Note this requires the shapefiles to be loaded as layers to QGIS - have you got that?

Comment: @BERA , Thanks a mill, both are working: For a date fieldtype and For a string field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use pyqgis.

**For a date fieldtype:**

```py
import os, datetime

shapefolder = r'C:\GIS\data\folder' #Where you have your 75 shapefiles (and no other shapefiles, including in any subdirectories!)
newfieldname = 'fecha'

for root, folder, files in os.walk(shapefolder):
    #Find the shapefile
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root,file)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and fullpath.endswith('.shp'):
            print(fullpath)
            #Extract numbers from filename
            datename = ''.join([num for num in file if num.isdigit()])
            #Create a datetime object and convert to string in format 'YYYY-MM-DD', which is what a shapefile wants
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(datename, '%Y%m%d')
            newdatename = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            print(datename)
            #Add the field https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-adding-and-deleting-vector-layer-fields/
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(fullpath)
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(newfieldname, QVariant.Date)])
            layer.updateFields()
            
            #Update each feature with date https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381174/setting-all-the-values-in-a-attribute-field-to-the-same-value-with-pyqgis)
            attr_map = {}
            field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(newfieldname)
            for f in layer.getFeatures():
                attr_map[f.id()] = {field_index: newdatename}
            layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attr_map)
```

[image]

**For a string field:**

```
import os

shapefolder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\folder'
newfieldname = 'fecha'

for root, folder, files in os.walk(shapefolder):
    #Find the shapefile
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root,file)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and fullpath.endswith('.shp'):
            print(fullpath)
            
            #Extract numbers from filename
            datestr = ''.join([num for num in file if num.isdigit()])
            print(datestr)
         
            #Add the field
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(fullpath)
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(name=newfieldname, type=QVariant.String, len=10)])
            layer.updateFields()
            
            #Update each feature with date (in a fast way using an attribute map: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381174/setting-all-the-values-in-a-attribute-field-to-the-same-value-with-pyqgis)
            attr_map = {}
            field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(newfieldname)
            for f in layer.getFeatures():
                attr_map[f.id()] = {field_index: datestr}
            layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attr_map)
```